# SQL Error [22P02] does not recognise varchar converted to integer in the where clause

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have table TROQ which does have a field named cod defined as Varchar(13) (Postgres 11.8)

When the first four characters of cod are numeric it means it is "special troq".  Special Troqs, according to this numeric first four characters can be "Production" when this four numeric characters form a code that is less than 5000 and "Development" when the code is over 5000.  *This is just for the example, in the real problem there are many more cathegories to special troqs, but each of them forming a numeric range as for the example*

So I tried the following query:

```
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, substr(cod, 1, 4)::integer pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))) CT
where pref < 5000
```

Implementation for function isnumeric:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.isnumeric(text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
       x = $1::NUMERIC;
       RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
       RETURN FALSE;
END;
$function$
;
```

And I got error:

```
    SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «INFD» 
... Meaning about: Input sintax not valid for integer <<INFD>>
```

If I take off the where from the outer query:

```
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, substr(cod, 1, 4)::int pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))) CT
```

Then it throws no error message.  It shows all TROQ's whose first four characters have a numeric code.
But I find no way to apply any condition on this pref casted field.

Next thing I tried was all kind of castings on the where, some making sense others not, but with no improvement on the result... Meaning things like:

```
... where pref::varchar < '5000'
... where pref::numeric < 5000
```

Just in case the matter was about the casting, I tried to_number with same result (The query works with no error if I remove the where clause and gives this 22P02 error when I try to add a condition on casted field pref):

```
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, to_number(substr(cod, 1, 4), '0000') pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))) CT
where pref < 5000
```

Any explanation or help on the matter would be highly appreciated.  Thank you in advance

Script to reproduce the exercise with just four records:

```
CREATE TABLE public.troq (
    cod varchar(13) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO public.troq (cod) VALUES 
('1234Trala')
,('Tururu')
,('4532Vargas')
,('n4567Titi')
;

(Troq records that should be recovered would be 1234Trala and 4532Vargas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PostgreSQL flattens the subquery and optimizes the query so that the condition `pref < 5000` is evaluated first, because PostgreSQL thinks that that is cheaper:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF)
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, substr(cod, 1, 4)::integer pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))) CT                  
where pref < 5000;
                                     QUERY PLAN
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on troq
   Filter: (((substr(cod, 1, 4))::integer < 5000) AND isnumeric(substr(cod, 1, 4)))
(2 rows)
```

That [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) and as it to be expected:

> The order of evaluation of subexpressions is not defined.

One trick you can do is to tell PostgreSQL that the function is very cheap (I set it `IMMUTABLE` at the same time, because it is):

```
ALTER FUNCTION isnumeric COST 1 IMMUTABLE;
```

That changes the execution plan, so that your function is evaluated first, and the error is avoided:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF)
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, substr(cod, 1, 4)::integer pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))) CT
where pref < 5000;
                                     QUERY PLAN
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on troq
   Filter: (isnumeric(substr(cod, 1, 4)) AND ((substr(cod, 1, 4))::integer < 5000))
(2 rows)
```

But that is of course not totally reliable (the other expression might also be very “cheap”), and a better solution would be to add an optimizer barrier like `OFFSET 0` to the subquery that will prevent it from being flattened:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF)
select cod, pref
from 
(select cod, substr(cod, 1, 4)::integer pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4))
OFFSET 0) CT
where pref < 5000;
                  QUERY PLAN                  
══════════════════════════════════════════════
 Subquery Scan on ct
   Filter: (ct.pref < 5000)
   ->  Seq Scan on troq
         Filter: isnumeric(substr(cod, 1, 4))
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for the really plain explanation of the problem.  I would say this is an error from postgres concerning standard SQL (Subquery should be evaluated first, says in the wikipedia) Fine that optimizer improves speed but I believe it should never change the sense of the query.  Am I right on this concern or I should start looking at every query from the optimizer point of view in Postgres and in other RDBMS as for example Oracle too?  Really interested in your opinion on this @Laurenz, as I can read and appreciate much of your knowledge on the matter spread all over Stack Overflow.

Comment: Never thought of that use for offset, in fact I probably never used offset at all.  I had the idea it would be used in combination with limit, I did not think it would affect in this way to the optimiser and it certainly gives new options for things to try on a query.  Postgress pages (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-limit.html)  say: "OFFSET 0 is the same as omitting the OFFSET clause"  I guess that is not so concerning the optimiser... Good to learn.  Really.

Comment: Yes, `OFFSET 0` is a trick - don't know if it is documented. I have added a link to the PostgreSQL documentation that explicitly says that you cannot expect a certain evaluation order. I couldn't find anything about that in the SQL standard, and I couldn't find your Wikipedia quote either.

Comment: You are right.  The wikipedia on SQL is quite an index for standars.  Sorry about that, I checked spanish version (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and it says clearly: "La subconsulta (consulta interna), se ejecuta antes de la consulta principal; el resultado de la subconsulta es utilizado por la consulta principal (consulta externa)." Which means subquery (Internal query) is executed before the main query; The result of the subquery is used by the main query (External query)"
I thought this would just be the translation for English wiki on the matter.  But is not.

Comment: [I have complained](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n:SQL#Falta_una_referencia_para_la_orden_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n_de_subconsultas) and asked for a quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a regular expression to validate the first 4 characters are digits, and forgo the is_numeric function all together.

```
select cod, pref
from 
    (select cod, to_number(substr(cod, 1, 4), '0000') pref
       from troq
      where  cod ~ '^\d{4}' 
    ) s
where pref < 5000;
```

Now,  regular expressions tend to be slower. But is it slower than substring, function call, type conversion, assignment, exception handling? Only testing would tell.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried doing it in a different way and it worked.  Don´t understand why though.  The solution that did work:

```
with CT as
(select cod, to_number(substr(cod, 1, 4), '0000') pref
from troq
where isnumeric(substr(cod,1, 4)))
select * from CT 
where pref < 5000;
```

I guess this way I make *more* sure that the optimiser executes first the inner query, but as short as I do know from SQL I did not think I would be having to make sure of that in any event.

Comment: That won't work reliably from PostgreSQL v12 on, because then CTEs are no longer an optimizer barrier.

Comment: In my opinion, that, just by itself is a good reason not to upgrade to PostgreSQL v12.  And queries whose result depend on optimiser decisions is a concept that makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: No, it is not. From v12 on, you say `WITH ct AS MATERIALIZED (...)` to get the same behavior.

Comment: Sorry I edited while you were answering I am afraid.  Well if materialised views or queries is the solution, I guess I don´t have to bother about optimising anymore.  Right?

Comment: Ah, no, that's not a materialized view. It just tells the optimizer to *not* optimize the CTE together with the main query, but to calculate it separately before the main query, just like it is done before v12. It is a compatibility feature mostly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Laurenz.  I got mixed up with term materialised.  Yes that makes it compatible and gives a way to solve the problem in any event.  Good to know as a way to skip the optimiser just in case for this matter or any other test too, I guess.